# Django 1.4: Tests are very slow

Tags: python, django, performance

I am working on a old code base which still uses Django 1.4

This means the nice flag `--keepdb` is not available.

Running a single test like this takes 50 seconds:

```
time manage.py test myapp.tests.test_foo.FooTestCase.test_something
```

My `test_something` method is fast. It is the creation of the test-DB which takes so long.

50 seconds is too long for a productive edit-test-cycle. What can I do (except faster hardware)?

Comment: I'd have taken this as a strong hint that you need to upgrade.  Django 1.4 is 10 years old, and EOL since 2015.  And it requires Python 2.7 which is also EOL since Jan 1st 2020.

Comment: I know.  Being stuck on an old version is painful.  But eventually you'll have to pay down the technical debt.  And it is probably less effort than you think ...

Comment: Yes.  I do feel productive telling you this.  There are a surprisingly large number of people who do not see obvious things.  Maybe you do.  But many other people reading this Q&A in the future will not see the obvious lesson here.  (Which is a significant part of why they are stuck in this hole ...)

Comment: P.S. Another option may be to use an in-memory version of the database for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack the option `--keepdb` into your source code.

You need to edit the file `django/db/backends/creation.py` like this:

```
256c256,259
<         self._create_test_db(verbosity, autoclobber)
---
>         skip = True
> 
>         if not skip:
>             self._create_test_db(verbosity, autoclobber)
264,281c267,285
<         # Report syncdb messages at one level lower than that requested.
<         # This ensures we don't get flooded with messages during testing
<         # (unless you really ask to be flooded)
<         call_command('syncdb',
<             verbosity=max(verbosity - 1, 0),
<             interactive=False,
<             database=self.connection.alias,
<             load_initial_data=False)
< 
<         # We need to then do a flush to ensure that any data installed by
<         # custom SQL has been removed. The only test data should come from
<         # test fixtures, or autogenerated from post_syncdb triggers.
<         # This has the side effect of loading initial data (which was
<         # intentionally skipped in the syncdb).
<         call_command('flush',
<             verbosity=max(verbosity - 1, 0),
<             interactive=False,
<             database=self.connection.alias)
---
>         if not skip:
>             # Report syncdb messages at one level lower than that requested.
>             # This ensures we don't get flooded with messages during testing
>             # (unless you really ask to be flooded)
>             call_command('syncdb',
>                 verbosity=max(verbosity - 1, 0),
>                 interactive=False,
>                 database=self.connection.alias,
>                 load_initial_data=False)
> 
>             # We need to then do a flush to ensure that any data installed by
>             # custom SQL has been removed. The only test data should come from
>             # test fixtures, or autogenerated from post_syncdb triggers.
>             # This has the side effect of loading initial data (which was
>             # intentionally skipped in the syncdb).
>             call_command('flush',
>                 verbosity=max(verbosity - 1, 0),
>                 interactive=False,
>                 database=self.connection.alias)
391,393c395,398
<         time.sleep(1)
<         cursor.execute("DROP DATABASE %s"
<                        % self.connection.ops.quote_name(test_database_name))
---
> 
>         #time.sleep(1)
>         #cursor.execute("DROP DATABASE %s"
>         #               % self.connection.ops.quote_name(test_database_name))
```

Now running the test takes 6 instead of 50 seconds.

If you modify the database schema, then you need to set `skip = False` for one run.

Comment: I pity you that you have to maintain a django 1.4 code base :D